# How to exclude space when reading input

Tags: c++

I want to read an input by user.

Example: If user inputs `233 245` (consider the space).

i need to assign it to variable like

```
a=233;
b=245;
```

How do i do this in c++?

Comment: What is the input type?

Comment: `int a,b;std::cin>>a>>b;`

Comment: Then why you tagged it with C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int a,b;

  // Get values
  std::cin >> a >> b;

  // Print out values
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
}
```

This reads user input from standard input to the variables a and b, and then prints them to standard output

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer villekulla :-)